# Uknown Error after updating PayPalCoreSDK

Tags: paypal

I update the PayPalCoreSDK to the most recent version today because I was getting OAuth Errors. After I updated everything I continue to get an error but it is an undescriptive error. Below is the error that gets logged:

```
ERROR PayPal.Exception.PayPalException [(null)] Exception in HttpConnection Execute:      The request was aborted: The request was canceled.
PayPal.Exception.PayPalException: Exception in HttpConnection Execute: The request was     aborted: The request was canceled. ---> System.Net.WebException: The request was aborted:     The request was canceled. ---> System.IO.IOException: Cannot close stream until all bytes     are written.
at System.Net.ConnectStream.CloseInternal(Boolean internalCall, Boolean aborting)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Net.ConnectStream.CloseInternal(Boolean internalCall, Boolean aborting)
at System.Net.ConnectStream.System.Net.ICloseEx.CloseEx(CloseExState closeState)
at System.Net.ConnectStream.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
at System.IO.Stream.Close()
at System.IO.StreamWriter.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
at System.IO.TextWriter.Dispose()
at PayPal.HttpConnection.Execute(String payLoad, HttpWebRequest httpRequest)
```

The request is returning a bearer response. Anyone have any thoughts on how i can fix this?? I am currently using the Sandbox information.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there was a bug in the paypal SDK for something else i was trying to do with addresses array. PayPal finally emailed me about my ticket months after I reported the issue.